# remove inner text from xml node in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

How can i remove the innertext from an xml object via powershell.

cosider:

```
<XML>
    <AddServer>win-coll3.astest.org</AddServer>
  <SERVERS>
    <Server load="119" url="win-coll.astest.org"/>
    <Server load="119" url="win-coll2.astest.org"/>
  </SERVERS>
</XML>
```

I Want to clear out the `AddServer` section

i tried:
    `$FileAsXMLObject.xml.Remove("AddServer")` but didnt work

I dont want to delete the section - just cleared out. somesthing like this:

```
<XML>
    <AddServer> </AddServer>
  <SERVERS>
    <Server load="119" url="win-coll.astest.org"/>
    <Server load="119" url="win-coll2.astest.org"/>
  </SERVERS>
</XML>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to clear the value of that element. This will work:

```
$FileAsXMLObject.xml.AddServer = [string]::Empty
```

Comment: i am able to echo out the innerText of AddServer, but if if try to assign the empty value, i get this error: Property 'AddServer' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\script.ps1:9 char:1 
+ $servers.xml.AddServer = [string]::Empty
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Comment: How are you setting `$servers`? In your question you're using `$FileAsXMLObject` - I'm assuming this is an XML object with an entire file loaded?

Comment: servers is initialized via `[xml]$servers = get-content servers.xml`.
`servers.xml`'s content is the above one.
I tried `$servers.xml.AddServer = [string]::Empty`, and got the errormessage: Property 'AddServer' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
+ $servers.xml.AddServer = [string]::Empty
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Comment: Very strange - works fine for me. What version of powershell are you using? What's the output if you just type `$servers.xml`?

Comment: i think i figured it out. i missed to mention my first line in my servers.xml `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. if i remove this line it works. - but why? BTW: PS Powershell on WinServ2012R2 (think it is 4.0)